# No article with president

Tags: articles, zero-article

If I were president...

Why don't we have article "a"  before "president"?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is what "Advanced Language Practice" by Macmillan says about it:

[image]

Of course, since "president" is a countable noun, we can say "a president" (*She is a president and he is a doctor*). Note that we use "a" before "president" just like before any other singular noun when we are talking about a job, occupation:

> If I were a teacher, I would work with children.
>
> If I were a builder, I would have to be physically strong.
>
> If I were a president, I would probably feel stressed out.

When we talk about being the political leader of a particular country (and it's a unique title for that country, that is there is only one president in that country), we can use "the" or we can omit it (see the explanation of "Advanced Language Practice" above).

Therefore, "If I were President" = "If I were the President."

But "If I were a president" is just different. It's like "If I were *some* president."